# Access me dice que hay un error de sintaxis en INSERT INTO y no lo encuentro

Tags: ms-access-2013

Estoy haciendo una base de datos y a la hora de programar un botón de guardar no funciona y me sale que hay un error en el INSERT INTO y no lo encuentro, tampoco lo señala. Este es el código:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Btn_guardar_Click()
    Dim SQL As String
    
    On Error GoTo ManipularError
    If formEmpty Then
        SQL = "INSERT INTO Clientes Cédula o Nit(C.C./Nit,Nombre y apellidos,Dirección,Ciudad,Departamento,Telefono fijo,Celular,Correo)" _
            & "VALUES(" & Me.TxtCC_Nit & ",'" & Me.TxtNombre & "','" & Me.Txt_Direc & "', " _
            & "" & Me.TxtCiudad & "','" & Me.TxtDepto & "'," & Me.TxtFijo & "," & Me.TxtCel & ",'" & Me.TxtCorreo & "',"
        CurrentDb.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError
        MsgBox "REGISTRO INSERTADO", vbInformation, "Avíso"
    End If
    Exit Sub
    
ManipularError:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Avíso"
End Sub

Private Function formEmpty() As Boolean
    Dim Ctrl As Variant
    
    On Error GoTo ManipularError
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If IsNull(Ctrl) Then
            MsgBox "FALTAN CAMPOS DE LLENAR" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Verifique.", vbExclamation, "Avíso":  Exit Function
        End If
        formEmpty = True
    Next Ctrl
    Exit Function
    
ManipularError:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Avíso"
End Function
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: como se llama la tabla?

Comment: La tabla se llama Clientes Cédula o Nit, y no te entiendo, como asi que tu codigo siempre debe ir en texto?

Comment: si. si pegas una imagen, es dificil ver lo que pasa.. hay que agrandarla, acercarla, alejarla... y si estas en un celular.. ni siquiera se ve... con que pegues el codigo, que es mucho mas facil ademas de hacer, podemos ayudarte mejor... ademas de una imagen, nadie puede pegar tu codigo... si hay que probarlo, hay que escribirlo a mano...

Comment: y si tus tablas y tus campos tienen nombres que incluyen espacios, entonces los mismos deben ir entre []...

Comment: Ya inserte el codigo arriba para que puedan ver mejor, Ya lo probe con los corchetes y me sucede lo mismo

Comment: mostra como lo probaste.. va con corchetes...

Comment: lo probe asi  SQL = "INSERT INTO [Clientes Cédula o Nit](C.C./Nit,[Nombre y apellidos],Dirección,Ciudad,Departamento,[Telefono fijo],Celular,Correo)" _

Answer (score 1):

Claramente tienes no uno, sino varios errores de sintaxis. Sin conocer el tipo de datos de la tabla, te propondría:

-Todos los campos que insertas, hazlo rodeados con comillas simples.

-Cuando termina la serie de valores a insertar (`values`) debes poner     un paréntesis.

-Aquellos nombres de objetos (tablas, campos) que tienen espacios o    caracteres especiales deben ir entre corchetes.

```
 SQL = "INSERT INTO [Clientes Cédula o Nit] ([C.C./Nit], [Nombre y apellidos], Dirección, Ciudad, Departamento, [Telefono fijo], Celular, Correo)" _
        & " VALUES ('" & Me.TxtCC_Nit & "', '" & Me.TxtNombre & "','" & Me.Txt_Direc & "', " _
        & "'" & Me.TxtCiudad & "','" & Me.TxtDepto & "', '" & Me.TxtFijo & "'," _
        & "'" & Me.TxtCel & "' ,'" & Me.TxtCorreo & "')"
CurrentDb.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Copie y pegue tu código y me dice que hay un error con el C.C./Nit porque esta entre corchetes, se los quite y sigue saliendo lo mismo

Comment: Asegúrate que el nombre del campo `C.C./Nit` sea idéntico al de la tabla, incluidos puntos y espacios

Comment: A la hora ejecutarse sale un aviso que dice desbordamiento, que significa?

Comment: Significa que algún valor que introduces tiene un tamaño superior al que acepta el campo

Comment: como nota al margen, por mas que las bases de datos lo permitan, diria que nunca se usan espacios o caracteres especiales en los nombres de los campos, justamente para evitar estos problemas...

Comment: Como nota al margen adicional, recomiendo que nunca se generen instrucciones concatenando valores si se quiere evitar la inyección de SQL.

Comment: Ya cambie el tamaño de los campos y me sigue apareciendo desbordamiento, que sucede?

Comment: Si te sigue saliendo desbordamiento, es que no cambiaste el **tipo de datos**. Cada tipo de datos admite un *tamaño* de valores. Por ejemplo, `Byte` admite números de 0 a 255. Si intentas almacenar un valor superior a 255, te dará error. Mira bien el tipo de datos de cada uno de tus campos. Puedes ver los tipos de datos aquí: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/tipos-de-datos-para-bases-de-datos-de-escritorio-de-access-df2b83ba-cef6-436d-b679-3418f622e482